# Why suddenly some things have disappeared from the body section?

Tags: element

I've been working on a website and from time to time some elements are disappearing from the document. I've figured out that it's because in CSS document the early lines are not fully commented. I would like to ask why if even such a tiny thing like Skeleton's default version text is not fully commented or some of the classes or id's don't have a closing bracket then the whole website has layout problems. What skeleton's version has to do with page's body color ? This is really confusing.

Here is the HTML and CSS :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vIchA

I would be glad with any help. Yours truly,

D.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have to guess how to render bad code.  Sometimes they will guess and render it correctly, other times it will look weird.

Different browsers are likely to render it differently (though error handling standards are improving)

In this case, your demo lacks a "/" at the start, which means it is trying to render the comments as css.  The comments are not css, so it gets confused and does the best it can.

A quick way to find any bugs in the css is to use this:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thanks Richard. Can you explain to me in easy way what means parsing error ? It means that a piece of code does not have a closing bracket for example ?

Comment: It is any error caused by a coding mistake that occurs when the script is executed.  In many languages, an error would just stop the script working altogether.  In css, it will muddle through the best it can.  So, yes, not having a closing bracket would likely cause a parsing error in css.